# Script for loading csv to powershell output

Tags: powershell, csv, date, input, output

I need help with a powershell script, a simple script.

I have a .csv File with basic simple values, looking like this:

> ```
>    TimeDate; PingTime
>    dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm; x ms;
>    dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm; x ms;
>    dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm; x ms;
>    dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm; x ms;
> ```

Basically it has 10 rows with data corresponding to 10 minutes. Every minute one row.

I need a powershell Script which reads everytime it is fired/started one row at a time.

I was thinking that It might work like this:

The powershell searches for the .csv File, it searches it in a directory and automatically takes the newest .csv File available. (Every 10minutes, a File appears (from a different script) in the directory) So when a File appears in the directory, Powershell chooses the newest File, reads the first row of the .csv and passes an output like this:

write-host "TimeDate, Pingtime"

The second time it will run, powershell would know that it is using the same .csv File, so it would take the second row and pass it out with write-host.

This procedure will repeat for the 3rd, 4th and 10th time, so after the 10th time, a new .csv File will be present in the directory, so powershell takes this File, and begins to print the first row again.

Currently I have something like this:

```
$dir = "C:\temp\"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$file = Import-Csv C:\temp\$latest   # $latest has Filename of the newest File in dir
([string]$file[0]).Split(',')[0] | out-host;
```

This writes something like this: 
@{DateTime;Ping Time=12.09.2018 17:37;0 msec}

and I need and output like this:

```
write-host $date:$ptime
```

which prints:
12.09.2018 17:37:7 ms

And also I would need the functionality to print everytime it runs the next row in line.

Comment: Instead of `LastAccessTime`, could you use `LastWriteTime`? It would always be the newest no matter whether a file is new or not. You would simply need to get the data from the CSV and then look at the last index each time.

Comment: Yeah, that would be maybe OK, but I think what I used is also OK. I will try both and choose the best when testing. Unrotunately that did not solve my problem, I have problems with reading the index of the csv.